# Capturar checkbox cuando es unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dispongo de un listado de inputs tipo checkbox, los cuales tienen valores numéricos, para reunir todos tengo una array que en un evento click se van incluyendo, el problema es que en el momento de deseleccionar no me captura el input y su valor.

```js
var checks = [];

$('.elemento').click(function () {
   
  if (checkValue($(this).val(), checks)) {
    //Eliminar valor en la array
    checks = jQuery.grep(checks, function (value) {     
      return value != $(this).val();//aqui causa el error ya que $(this).val() apunta a window
    });
  } else {
    checks.push($(this).val());
  }
  console.log(checks);
});

function checkValue(value, arr) {
  var status = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var name = arr[i];
    if (name == value) {
      status = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return status;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul role="group">
  <li>
    <span style="color:red" id="255">

      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="seleccionados" class="elemento" value="255">
        <i></i>Elemento 1
      </label>

    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="color:red" id="267">

      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="seleccionados" class="elemento" value="267">
        <i></i>Elemento 2
      </label>

    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="color:red" id="299">

      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="seleccionados" class="elemento" value="299">
        <i></i>Elemento 3
      </label>

    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="color:red" id="301">

      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="seleccionados" class="elemento" value="301">
        <i></i>Elemento 4
      </label>

    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="color:red" id="325">

      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="seleccionados" class="elemento" value="325">
        <i></i>Elemento 5
      </label>

    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="color:red" id="216">

      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="seleccionados" class="elemento" value="216">
        <i></i>Elemento 6
      </label>

    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="color:red" id="298">

      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="seleccionados" class="elemento" value="298">
        <i></i>Elemento 7
      </label>

    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="color:red" id="300">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="seleccionados" class="elemento" value="300">
        <i></i>Elemento 8
      </label>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

El error que me muestra en mi consola es

> jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
>           at n.fn.init.val (VM1347 jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: Tienes que tener cuidado, el `$(this).val()` dentro de `jQuery.grep` tiene otro contexto por lo cual deberías de guardar el `$(this).val()` en una variable y usar esa variable en esa función.

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior Pues parece que has dado en el clavo, te animo a responder el por qué ocurre eso dentro de `jQuery.grep`